# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.Handler

Tags: java, jar, noclassdeffounderror, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am working on YouTube broadcast sample java program. I have created a sample program imported code from

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java

And, I have imported necessary dependencies/jars. But, when I try to run program, it throws exception on this line :

```
LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8080).build();
```

below exception :

```
Throwable: org/mortbay/jetty/Handler
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/jetty/Handler
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver$Builder.build(LocalServerReceiver.java:169)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.live.Auth.authorize(Auth.java:80)
    at com.google.api.services.samples.youtube.cmdline.live.CreateBroadcast.main(CreateBroadcast.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.jetty.Handler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 3 more
```

And when I import `org.mortbay.jetty.jar`

I get this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/extensions/java6/auth/oauth2/VerificationCodeReceiver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver$Builder.build(LocalServerReceiver.java:180)
    at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.VerificationCodeReceiver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: No I am importing jars using Build Path

Comment: Added an answer specifying the jar you should be including.

Comment: What exactely do you mean with `when I import org.mortbay.jetty.jar`? You add an `import statement` in the code? You put the jar file in the `classpath`? If you are using maven for your project post the `pom.xml`.

Comment: @SubOptimal I am not using maven, using build path. Please check my first 3 comments with shruti1810 you will come to know what I did

Comment: @VVB Could you please show your `classpath` when you run your code.

Comment: [A new community member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7030000/d-boden-pollack) asks if you solved this, VVB, and if so how?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using maven, please include this jar in your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, you can download this jar `org.mortbay.jetty.jar` and include it.

Comment: The github link that you are pointing to has a pom.xml, and it does not have this jar included.

Comment: Yes it didn't mention over there but shows CTE to get rid of that error

Comment: As per your second error, you should be adding this jar as well `google-oauth-client-java6-1.13.1-beta-sources.jar`

Comment: Is it giving the same error or some different error?

Comment: Can you unjar the package and check if it has this class? If not, the version you are using should be updated or degraded to a jar version whihch contains that class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78489/discussion-between-vvb-and-shruti1810).